# ASCII character 27 (left arrow) disappears when using the system() function in C++

Tags: c++

While writing a program I encountered a bug. When I don't use the system() function in my code, e.g. system("CLS"); character 27 (that is the left arrow in the ASCII code) is displayed correctly, but after using this function this character turns into an empty space. I should add that this does not happen with any other ASCII character.
Here is some code:

```
printf("%c %c",27,26);
```

And it displays: ← →
but

```
system("CLS");
printf("%c %c",27,26);
```

displays:   →
Anyone had a similar problem and dealt with it? I would like to find out how to solve it because I need both the system() and the left arrow.

Comment: Where are you getting the information that ASCII 27 is the left arrow character?  Character 27 is the escape (a non-printable).  Anything below ASCII 32 is considered a control character, and is not guaranteed to print anything.

Comment: Yes, sure there are not printable chars so perhaps I have misspoken, but code of left arrow is 27 so that's why i said this. Anyway is it possible to use system() (which, as I understand it, converts displayable characters into control characters) with character codes from 0-32?

Comment: You still didn't mention where you got the information that a left arrow is an ASCII 27.  Believe it or not, where you got this information is partially (or fully) the information required to display such a character.  If it's from a certain ASCII table, then you need to know what code page that ASCII table represents.

Comment: I wrote this: https://pastecode.io/s/MS82qm9PAW and from this I've obtained the numbers defining these characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `←` character in Unicode is codepoint [`U+2190 LEFTWARDS ARROW`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2190/index.htm).

In [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (aka the DOS OEM codepage), for instance, byte `0x1B` (dec 27) is used to display Unicode codepoint `U+2190`.  See [Console Code Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages) for more details.

So, it is possible that maybe calling `system("CLS")` is resetting the current codepage of the terminal, which would explain why printing `0x1B` no longer displays as `←`.  Try calling `system("CHCP 437")` or `SetConsoleOutputCP(437)` afterwards to change it back.

Or, you could simply stop relying on printing ANSI strings using codepages at all.  Print out Unicode strings instead, using `wprintf()` or `WriteConsoleW()`, or since your question is tagged as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), use `std::wcout`.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I was able to solve this problem as follows: 

system("CHCP 65001");

printf("Character: \u2190\n");

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, on the windows console, the ASCII codes 0-5, 11, 16-26 and 28-31 have printable symbols, the others below 32 really are control codes and may do something very odd

char(27) really is escape and char(24) cancels it. char(7) sounds the bell.

Comment: That actually depends on the codepage used to display the symbols.  Most codepages don't display printable symbols for control characters.

Comment: I haven't played with code pages or control codes since the days of DOS and the ANSI driver and I haven't a clue what the default code page for the Windows console is but on my system the codes I mentioned do print 

Comment: "*I haven't a clue what the default code page for the Windows console is*" - so query it: [`GetConsoleOutputCP()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp).  Or, just look at the console's window properties.

Comment: CP 850 is default on my system, whats yours ?

Comment: The first 128 bytes of [codepage 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) are the same as [codepage 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), so byte `0x1B` is displayed as `←` in both codepages.

Comment: Hmm, don't work like that on my system. If I do cout << char(27); then it prints nothing and the following characters are treated as control codes until I do cout << char(24) to terminate the sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229674/discussion-between-graham-dearsley-and-remy-lebeau).